# XStream and Object class serialization

Tags: java, xstream

I have beans which have Objects which can contain different types. Now when I create XML it will add class attribute to serialized object. I would like to change that for example class simple name.

Example Java:

```
public class MyParentClass {

private Object childObjectAttribute; // Can be any instance of any interface ...

// Getters & setters etc..
```

XStream initialization:

```
public XStream getXStream()
{
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    Class<?>[] c = { MyInterfaceImpl.class }; // MyInterfaceImpl has of course @XStreamAlias("MyInterface")
    xstream.processAnnotations(c);
    xstream.alias(MyInterface.class.getSimpleName(), MyInterface.class, MyInterfaceImpl.class);
    return xstream;
}
```

Example XML:

```
<myParentClass>
    <childObjectAttribute class="com.example.PossibleClass"/>
</myParentClass>
```

I would like to change com.example.PossibleClass to PossibleClass or something else. Is that possible?

Comment: The only thing I can say about it is that ``PossibleClass`` without package name can cause deserialization problems when multiple packages contain a class of that name. For this, it may be impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can! It's helps to reduce the size of generated document. It's a good practice to do so.
Use [XStream.alias()](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#alias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) method.

This works for me.

```
PersonX person = new PersonX("Tito", "George");
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("MyPerson", PersonX.class);
String str = xstream.toXML(person);
System.out.println(str);
```

Without alias

```
<co.in.test.PersonX>
  <firstName>Tito</firstName>
  <lastName>George</lastName>
</co.in.test.PersonX>
```

With alias

```
<MyPerson>
  <firstName>Tito</firstName>
  <lastName>George</lastName>
</MyPerson>
```

Is the below approach not working?

```
workxstream.alias("PossibleClass", PossibleClass.class);
```

Comment: Updated question to contain XStream initialization.

Comment: Yes it works for String, Integer etc. and even Interfaces, but I have class Object, which seems to cause problems, because it can contain any class.

Comment: is 'workxstream.alias("PossibleClass", PossibleClass.class);' not working?

Comment: Now it works, I don't really know what was problem, because now it seems to  work with your examples. Thanx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want the simple name of the class and you know the object's package you can:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.aliasPackage("", "com.example");
```

Output xml:

```
<myParentClass>
    <childObjectAttribute class="PossibleClass"/>
</myParentClass>
```

Comment: Please ignore this answer, I found this hack does not work because 1 package with blank alias causes deserialization problems with classes of another packages.